# Cannot found dependency I had in visual studio when running my app

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dependencies

I had two project and one of them is used as a dependency in the other.

For example Project A need Project B to work.

To had this dependency in visual studio I click "Add dependency", go to "Project" and select the one I need.

When build my solution (A) everything is ok but when I use A outside of visual studio, I get this error :

[image]

How should I load Project B into Project A to be right ?

**=== Edited ===**

Original question from [Autodesk Forum](https://forums.autodesk.com/t5/revit-api-forum/call-an-externalevent-from-another-assembly/m-p/11003666/highlight/false#M62167)

**=== Edited (again) ===**

Subscribe to **AssemblyResolve** seems to solve the problem.
I use it like this in main :

`AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += ResolveAssembly;`

And need to create create this method :

```
private Assembly ResolveAssembly(object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
    {
        string name = args.Name.Split(',')[0];

        return Assembly.LoadFile(@"C:\ProgramData\Letitbim\" + name + ".dll");
    }
```

Rebuild my project start again and now I got this :

[image]

Comment: If A needs B and B needs A, then you have a circular dependency, That is not going to work.

Comment: There is no circular dependency here, I execute A with B as a dependency (I edited my post sorry for the confusion)

Comment: There is still some confusion: "How should I load Project A into Project B to be right?". You mean B into A.

Comment: I said Project A need Project B to work. So B is a dependency of A. (edited again sorry again)

Comment: The output of B should be copied to A automatically during build. If you have some external dependencies (files that are used by B, but not a product of B) then you might have to copy them in a postbuild event. First step is to pinpoint exactly what you are missing. Here the InnerException on FileNotFoundException might be helpful.

Comment: Build isn't my main problem because, when I start A, of course VS found dependency in build folder but in case of an installation (as standalone application), B dependency isn't found because folder and installation path change. To avoid that I build B, copy it to final application installation folder and then, in A, I add B dependency by search it on my PC. What if end user change folder installation path ?